# Firefox Addon error: Module `path` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/http.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, firefox-addon

I am writing a Firefox add-on, 
OS is Windows10, node v5.8.0 and npm v3.5.3, Firefox v.45.0

The line causing the error is:

```
var path = require("path");
```

And the error message is:

```
Message: Module `http` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/http.js
```

The following works though:

```
var system = require("sdk/system");
```

I tried `require` with other core modules of node and all of them return the error message above (for instance `path` and `util`). It seems like none of the core node modules work or can be found.

I have reistalled node and npm today a few times (following troubleshooting and responses to similar questions), `NODE_PATH` is set to`%AppData%\npm`, I have `...\npm\bin` and `...\npm\node_modules` in my `PATH`.

Any ideas and help how to resolve the above would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

al

Comment: Why would node's built-in modules be available in Firefox?

Comment: @mscdex Because it supposed to. Try [`var path = require("sdk/fs/path");`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/fs_path).

Comment: Can you give links to documentation that states that node's built-in modules should be available to Firefox addons? I have never seen that before.

Comment: The above piece of code is clickable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/fs_path It's not all node modules (yet?) but some are available like fs.path or child_process.

Comment: @ShanShan - Thanks a lot for this - it helped.

Comment: @ShanShan get some points move to solution ;) and al37 please accept Shanshan's solution you get some points too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, [fs/path's doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/fs_path) is empty but using [`child_process's one`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process), one can infer that the require should be `var path = require("sdk/fs/path");`